# Can you help with this exponential decay question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Suppose that 100 kg of a radioactive substance decays to 80 kg in 20 years.

a) Find the half-life of the substance (round to the nearest year).

b) Write down a function $y(t)$ ($t$ in years) modeling the amount (in kg) of the radioactive substance at time $t$.

Comment: I have solved your problem. Please show your attempt before I share the solution.

Comment: I did and got this 80/100=ln2/T
Where T is T=lnsqrt32

Comment: I posted the answer. You can confirm your working.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
You have the radioactive decay law:
$$N(t)=N_0e^{-\lambda t}$$
You have $N=80$ the time $t$ and $N_0=100$ deduce $\lambda$.
Then half life $T$ is:
$$N=\dfrac {N_0}2$$
$$\dfrac {N_0}2=N_0e^{-\lambda T}$$
$$\implies \dfrac 12=e^{-\lambda T}$$
$$ T=\dfrac {\ln 2}{\lambda}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A_t$ is the amount left at time $t$, $A_0$ is the initial amount and $k$ is the rate constant for the first order reaction, we know for the radioactive decay (which is first order reaction) -
\begin{align}
A_t &= A_0e^{-kt} \tag i \\
\text{or  } \ln \left(\frac{A_t}{A_0}\right) &= -kt.
\end{align}

As $A_0 = 100$, $A_t = 80$, $t = 20$,
\begin{align}
\implies \ln \left(\frac{80}{100}\right) &= -20k. \\
k &= -\frac{\ln 0.8}{20} \tag {ii}
\end{align}

At half life, $\displaystyle \ln \left(\frac{50}{100}\right) = -kt_{1/2}$ or $$ t_{1/2} = - \frac {\ln (0.5)}{k} = 20 \times \frac {\ln (0.5)} {\ln(0.8)} \approx 62.1 \text{ years}.$$

Now, find $k$ using equation (ii) and plug $k$ and $A_0 = 100$ into equation (i) and that is your answer to (b).

Comment: Thank you so much!